# Linear Algebra in Python: Calculating Eigenvectors for 3x3 Matrix

Tags: python, linear-algebra, eigenvalue, eigenvector

I am using Python to derive the eigenvectors associated with the eigenvalues in a 3x3 matrix.  My code is returning correct eigenvalues but wrong eigenvectors.

```
A = np.array([[-2, -4,  2],
              [-2,  1,  2],
              [4,   2,  5]])
print (A)
print ('-------------------------------------------------------')

eigenvalues, eigenvectors = np.linalg.eig(A) # must use this line of code exactly 
print(f'eigenvalues of matrix A are:{eigenvalues}')
print ('-------------------------------------------------------')
print(f'eigenvectors of matrix A are:{eigenvectors}')
```

[image]

For example, the eigenvector associated with value 6 should be [1, 6, 16], not what the code output.

Comment: There are infinitely many eigenvectors for each eigenvalue. The code works correctly.

Comment: From the numpy docs, the eigenvalues matrix is returned such that "The normalized (unit “length”) eigenvectors, such that the column v[:,i] is the eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue w[i]." Have a look at the last _column_ of the eigenvectors matrix. It is [1, 6, 16], only normalized.

Answer (score 3):

It is correct and you can check it by the eigenvector/eigenvalue condition for the second eigenvalue and eigenvector.

[image]

Where `u` is the eigenvector and `lambda` is its eigenvalue.
So we multiply the eigenvector `v[:,1]` by `A` and check that it is the same as multiplying the same eigenvector by its eigenvalue `w[1]`.

```
import numpy as np

>>> w, v = np.linalg.eig(A)
# w contains the eigenvalues. 
# v contains the corresponding eigenvectors, one eigenvector per column. 
# The eigenvectors are normalized so their Euclidean norms are 1
>>> u = v[:,1]
>>> print(u)
[ 0.53452248, -0.80178373, -0.26726124]

>>> lam = w[1]
>>> lam
3.0

>>> print(np.dot(A,u))
[ 1.60356745 -2.40535118 -0.80178373]
>>> print(lam*u)
[ 1.60356745 -2.40535118 -0.80178373]
```

Comment: And specifically, the eigenvectors returned by [`np.linalg.eig`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.eig.html) are normalized to unit length.

Comment: @PineNuts0 if this answers your question please accept it.

Answer (score 0):

See the key here is as said above the normalization process made by the NumPy library to display the array of the "Eigenvectors" **numerically** as it is **not** programmed to display something like

```
# when λ = 6
x_dash = np.array([[ 1*x],
                   [ 6*x],
                   [16*x]])
# and then you replace x with your lucky number that would save you some effort in math manipulation
```

, so in your case, you expect [1, 6, 16] as eigenvector for the 6 eigenvalues, that is OK, don't panic. You just have to recognize that the whole vector underwent a dot multiplication process with some constant that came from the vectorization, and in your case, it happens to be

> 0.05842062

1. 1 * 0.05842062 = 0.05842062
2. 6 * 0.05842062 = 0.35052372
3. 16 * 0.05842062 = 0.93472992

that is what you get with np.linalg library